# Iterate over particular child nodes in XML and save to CSV using Python

Tags: python, xml, csv

I've looked through a bunch of similar questions and didn't see an answer that solved this specifically. I haven't worked with XML files in python before and am on a time crunch, so I'm probably just overlooking the obvious. I have a bunch of XML files that I need to just grab two values from, for each provider record in the file. I need to save those in a csv.

I have some code that's pulling more than I'm expecting ...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse('xml/HSP-FullOutOfAreaSite03-DEC.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for PROVIDER in root.iter('PROVIDER'):
    for PROV_IDENTIFIER in PROVIDER:
        print(PROV_IDENTIFIER.text)
    for TAXONOMY_CODE in PROVIDER:
        print(TAXONOMY_CODE.text)
```

The XML has a bunch of repeating PROVIDER_GROUP's and for each provider in all the provider groups I need the provider's PROV_IDENTIFIER and TAXONOMY_CODE.

```
<PROVIDER_GROUP>
    <MASTER_GROUP_CODE>345093845</MASTER_GROUP_CODE>
    <TAX_ID>3095</TAX_ID>
    <GROUPNUMBER>16</GROUPNUMBER>
    <SITECOUNT>1</SITECOUNT>
    <CONTRACTS>
      <CONTRACT>
        <EFF_DATE>2002-01-01</EFF_DATE>
      </CONTRACT>
    </CONTRACTS>
    <PROVIDER_SITES>
      <PROVIDER_SITE>
        <PROV_MASTER_ID>18583783745</PROV_MASTER_ID>
        <MASTER_GROUP_CODE>584293845</MASTER_GROUP_CODE>
        <PROVIDERS>

          <PROVIDER>
            <PROVNO>123456</PROVNO>
            <NAME_FIRST>John</NAME_FIRST>
            <NAME_LAST>Doe</NAME_LAST>
            <NAME_CREDENTIAL>DDD</NAME_CREDENTIAL>
            <GENDER>M</GENDER>
            <PROV_IDENTIFIER>3459832385</PROV_IDENTIFIER>
            <TAXONOMIES>
              <TAXONOMY>
                <TAXONOMY_CODE>23498R98239X</TAXONOMY_CODE>
              </TAXONOMY>
            </TAXONOMIES>
            <HOSPRELATIONS>
              <HOSP>
                <NPI>1366896300</NPI>
              </HOSP>
            </HOSPRELATIONS>
          </PROVIDER>

         <PROVIDER>
            <PROVNO>123454</PROVNO>
            <NAME_FIRST>Jane</NAME_FIRST>
            <NAME_LAST>Doe</NAME_LAST>
            <NAME_CREDENTIAL>DDD</NAME_CREDENTIAL>
            <GENDER>F</GENDER>
            <PROV_IDENTIFIER>3945092358</PROV_IDENTIFIER>
            <TAXONOMIES>
              <TAXONOMY>
                <TAXONOMY_CODE>55598R98239X</TAXONOMY_CODE>
              </TAXONOMY>
            </TAXONOMIES>
            <HOSPRELATIONS>
              <HOSP>
                <NPI>34598345030</NPI>
              </HOSP>
            </HOSPRELATIONS>
          </PROVIDER>

        </PROVIDERS>
      </PROVIDER_SITE>
    </PROVIDER_SITES>
  </PROVIDER_GROUP>

  <PROVIDER_GROUP>
    <PROVIDER_SITES>
      <PROVIDER_SITE>
        <PROVIDERS>
         <!-- MORE PROVIDERS -->
        </PROVIDERS>
      </PROVIDER_SITE>
    </PROVIDER_SITES>
  </PROVIDER_GROUP>
```

And I need a CSV that just looks like:

```
PROV_IDENTIFIER | TAXONOMY_CODE
---------------------------------
210985345098    | 234R345359X
310495345091    | 456R345359X
534581039568    | 567R345359X
802869458327    | 234R345359X
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the XML into `bs4` and get them like this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

with open('xml/HSP-FullOutOfAreaSite03-DEC.xml', 'r') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'lxml')

# Get the data you want
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(
  [el.text for el in soup.find_all('prov_identifier')],
  [el.text for el in soup.find_all('taxonomy_code')]
)), columns=['PROV_IDENTIFIER', 'TAXONOMY_CODE'])

# Dump to csv
df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of BeautifulSoup. That certainly simplified things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example so you can get an idea on how to proceed:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('xml/HSP-FullOutOfAreaSite03-DEC.xml')
providers = tree.findall(".//PROVIDERS/PROVIDER")
agg = [
    (p.find('./PROV_IDENTIFIER').text,
        [t.text for t in p.findall(".//TAXONOMY_CODE")]) for p in providers]
```

If you run this against your XML sample you will get

```py
[('3459832385', ['23498R98239X']), ('3945092358', ['55598R98239X'])]
```

The first element in the tuple will have the `PROV_IDENTIFIER`, the second element will be a list of all the nested `TAXONOMY_CODE`elements.